# How do I use a button to start animation of a card sliding carousell using framer motion?

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend, framer-motion

I am trying to use framer motion to animate a image sliding carousel. I want the animation to only start when I press a button. The problem is that the animation starts before I even click on the button. I have my 5 images in an array. Upon my button click, the animation should be as so: the first image should shrink and fade out into the background while the remaining four image should all slide towards the left.

the subsequent animation should be: now that the first image has disappeared, the second image should shrink and fade out into the background while the remaining 3 images should all slide towards the left.

and so on and so forth until only the last image is visible, the animation should stop there.

```
 <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2 mt-32 ml-10">
        <div
          className="flex flex-row gap-10 overflow-x-scroll no-scrollbar scroll-smooth mx-5"
          ref={containerRef}
        >
          {images.map((image, index) => (
            <motion.img
              key={index}
              src={image}
              alt={`Image ${index + 1}`}
              initial={{ x: "+100%" }}
              animate={{
                opacity: index < currentIndex ? 0 : 1,
                scale: index < currentIndex ? 0 : 1,
                x: buttonClicked && index === currentIndex ? 0 : "-100%",
              }}
              transition={{ duration: 0.75 }}
            />
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-row mt-10 gap-12">
          <button
            className="flex bg-rose_ebony rounded-full w-[68px] h-[68px] items-center justify-center"
            onClick={() => {
              prevImage();
            }}
            disabled={currentIndex === 0}
          >
            <img src={arrow} className="" />
          </button>

          <button
            className="flex bg-rose_ebony rounded-full w-[68px] h-[68px] items-center justify-center"
            onClick={() => {
              nextImage();
            }}
            disabled={currentIndex === images.length - 1}
          >
            <img src={arrow} className="rotate-180" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

so the animation for the opacity and scale works correctly. but the x axis animation is broken. the images automatically slide to the left the moment my page loads. I want it to only slide when I click on the button.

Comment: const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);
  const nextImage = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
    setButtonClicked(true);
  };

  const prevImage = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex - 1);
  };

this is my nextImage and prevImage function

Answer (score 0):

The moment your piece of code loads, the animation starts. The buttons have no influence on that.

If you want the animation to run only after a button-click, then load a new component on button-click.
And that new component is animated.

The same for the next images: Load them in a small separate component and load that component on a button-click.